# KeyNotFoundException on MySql Query / C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am developing a software on C#, I must use MySQL connection on this program. I can connect to database. Visual Studio is throwing a exception on `ExecuteReader()` line.

```
Exception: KeyNotFoundException , "The given key was not present in the dictionary"
```

This is my code:

```
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder bag = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        bag.Server = "localhost";
        bag.UserID = "root";
        bag.Password = "123456";
        bag.Database = "randevu_takip";
        MySqlConnection baglan = new MySqlConnection();
        baglan.ConnectionString = bag.ToString();
        baglan.Open();

 MySqlCommand komut = new MySqlCommand();
        komut.Connection = baglan;
        komut.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        komut.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM kullanicilar;";

        MySqlDataReader oku = komut.ExecuteReader();

        while (oku.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(oku.GetString("sifre"));
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting error on line MySqlDataReader oku = komut.ExecuteReader();? or you get it inside loop?

Comment: @AshReva No, error is on ExecuteReader() line.

Comment: What if you try to select specific columns in your query instead of doing select * ?

Comment: My purpose this usage: `komut.CommandText = "SELECT id,kadi,sifre FROM kullanicilar WHERE kadi=@kadi;"; 
            komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kadi", txtKadi.Text);`

But Visual Studio throwing Exception I replaced it:             `komut.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM kullanicilar;"` with             `komut.CommandText = "SELECT id,kadi,sifre FROM kullanicilar";` result is unchanged

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved for me when I change my column Collation from utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci to utf8_general_ci.

Try to define same charset for connection and table.

```
var connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; Port=3307;  uid=your_name; Pwd=your_password; Database=your_database; charset=utf8;");
```

To change collation for tables you can use,

```
ALTER TABLE mytable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Comment: I had 3 varchar columns with different charsets.
Even a SELECT query that only used numerical columns produced above problem.
Above "ALTER" command changed all columns to utf8_general_ci.
After that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

***Stop MySql Server***

Add / Edit below configuration in mysql config file, i.e. **my.ini** file
Which is located in

> C:\ProgramData\MySql\MySql Server [version]

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

***Start MySql Server***